# Unfortunately, app name has stopped

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to write an easy app for Android using eclipse with plugins.
Here's the code:

```
package com.example.pushthebutton;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int counter = 30;
    TextView label;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int delay = 0; 
        int period = 1000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    label.setText(String.valueOf("Time left: "));
                    counter--;
                }
            }, delay, period);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

After I run it in the emulator, it says: "Unfortunately, app name has stopped."
Logcat:

```
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6452)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3696)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at com.example.pushthebutton.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:24)
03-26 15:05:47.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1269):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
03-26 15:05:47.659: E/StrictMode(628): null
```

I'm new to Java.. I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: You don't need to use `String.valueOf("Time left: ")`. `"Time left: "` is already a String.

Comment: @unholysampler
yeah, I didn't know about runOnUiThread then, so I thought I should cast it or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

You can not do like this.

```
label.setText(String.valueOf("Time left: "));
```

Do like this.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      //Update UI Here
   }
});
```

OR Handler to do this.

### Example

```
void startHeavyDutyStuff() {

  // Here is the heavy-duty thread
  Thread t = new Thread() {

      public void run() {
          while (true) {

              mResults = doSomethingExpensive();

              //Send update to the main thread
              messageHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(messageHandler, mResults)); 
          }

      }
  };
  t.start();
}

// Instantiating the Handler associated with the main thread.
private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {

      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
          switch(msg.what) {
              //handle update
              //.....
          }
      }

  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)
Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 4):

you can not update every View from a thread different from the UI Thread:

Change your code in this way:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    public void run() {
                        label.setText(String.valueOf("Time left: "));
                        counter--;
                        }
                  ));

            }
        }, delay, period);
}
```

In this way you are asking to Android to execute the `setText` call, on the `UI Thread`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
        public void run() {
        label.setText(String.valueOf("Time left: "));
                    counter--;
        }
            }
          }
        }, delay, period);
```

You are modifying UI thread from non-ui thread, i.e. timer.